Why ReentrantLock is better for virtual threads than synchronized?
I've visited some IT conference and on a session about virtual threads feature in Java 21+ was mentioned that synchronized might(!) be a problem for virtual threads because of pinning virtual thread and if it is a problem - usage of Lock could solve the problem.
I don't understand why Lock could be better than syncronized in context of virtual threads. I suppose that ReentrantLock could be a cause of the same pinning. isn't it ? If not - why ?

the synchronized keyword won't yield a platform thread if locked, while other implementations might.

There is no reason, in principle, why synchronized should perform any differently from the simplest use-case of ReentrantLock. Whatever the detailed answer turns out to be, it will be the the consequence of some arbitrary design decision—possibly some decision made long ago. Whatever it is, there is nothing other than time and money that would stop them from fixing it.

Your overuse of bold text is very annoying.  Do you talk to people face to face like that?  Do you yell several words in every sentence you speak?

Possible duplicate of this one? The answer though old, interestingly holds reference to virtual threads thanks to its edits.

@Naman the topic you linked is related but is definitely not duplicate

@VGR I expected it is easier to read instead raw text without code. Feel free to edit - I will appreciate it

The reason is simply that supporting object monitors is a lower-level VM change, whereas ReentrantLock was a smaller adjustment. Therefore it was likely deprioritized to a later milestone to focus on other core fundamentals. A recent early access build has added support so this issue is going away in a later JDK release.

Also related due to use of synchronize (System.out.println) inside virtual threads.

Virtual threads (fibers) are indicated for tasks that involve blocking, tasks that are not CPU-bound. Blocking tasks include those that perform file I/O, logging, network calls, database access, etc.
When a virtual thread is blocked, it can be swiftly switched out for another virtual thread to keep the CPU core busy. This quick switching between virtual threads is what makes them so highly performant.
The current implementation in Java 21 and Java 22 has a limitation. While code inside a synchronized block is running, Java cannot detect if that code is blocked or not. That task cannot be switched out for another virtual thread to execute. So that blocked code sits there doing nothing but waiting, and therefore that core sits there not doing any useful work.
This problem of a stuck virtual thread is called pinning. The blocked virtual thread is pinned to the host platform thread on that core. Pinning defeats the purpose of using virtual threads.
Brief pinning is not a problem. For example, a quick check of a protected guard variable. But a long-running chunk of pinned code is a problem. Such a long-running chunk of synchronized code should either (a) not be run on a virtual thread, or (b) should be rewritten to use a ReentrantLock rather than use synchronized.
The Project Loom team continues to examine this issue. A solution is in the works. So  a future version of Java may be free of this limitation.
By the way, a similar pinning situation is native code. Java code that uses JNI or Foreign Functions to call long-running native code should not be used in a virtual thread.
To understand virtual threads:

Study JEP 444.
See video presentations by Ron Pressler, Alan Bateman, and José Paumard.


Does pinning happens only after entrance into the synchronized block ? What about the case when the thread is blocked  waiting for synchronized block monitor is free ?

This does not answer the question. What is the difference between synchronized and reentrant? Why can JVM can detect a blocking operation in one but not another? The link to solution is somewhat useful, but does not cover the original problem either.

@Basilevs the difference is that the feature (carrier thread switching to another virtual thread) has been implemented for one of them but not yet for the other. But they’re already working on the implementation for the other, once this has been done, there will be no difference anymore. That’s all said in this answer.
